# Gaussian distribution with absolute value

Tags: probability, absolute-value

I am doing my homework about continuous random variable and Im struggling with this problem :

> Given a Gaussian random variable $T(85,10)$, find $c$ satisfying $\mathbb{P}[|T| < c] = 0.9$.

Could you help me with this question? Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

1. Can you find some transformation $X = (T-a)/b$ so that $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $b>0$?
2. Then $T = bX+a$ and your expression becomes
   $$
   \begin{split}
   0.9 &= \mathbb{P}[|T| < c] \\
       &= \mathbb{P}[-c < T < c] \\
       &= \mathbb{P}[-c < bX+a < c] \\
       &= \mathbb{P}\left[\frac{-c-a}{b} < X < \frac{c-a}{b}\right] \\
       &= \Phi\left(\frac{c-a}{b}\right) - \Phi\left(\frac{-c-a}{b}\right),
   \end{split}
   $$
   where $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF...

Comment: oh wow, I get it. thank you so much!

Comment: oops!! I still dont know how to find c, can you give me a hint ? At first, I thought that : because the probability is 0.9 then c must be greater than 85(because if c < 85 then P[|T|<c] < 0.5) , so -c < -85, then P[|T|<c] would approximately be P[T < c], which is 0.9, and then I can find c, but I'm not very sure that is the solution.

Comment: @NguyênChương do the first part, what are the values of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: T = 10X + 85, is that right ?

Comment: @NguyênChương $b = \sqrt{10}$ and $a$ is correct. Now plug them in, what do you get?

Comment: now I got CDF of two different values, and they are not symmetric with respect to the FX(x)-axis, I dont know how to deal with it